# Uploading files to Amazon S3 using asp.net - How to show progress bar?

Tags: asp.net, amazon-s3

Can someone please tell me how to show progress bar in asp.net when uploading files to amazon S3?

Answer (score 1):

I know its a little late and you might would have already solved this problem. But I will reply to it anyways.

I have been working on a problem of the same kind. After a lot of research and wasting time I found a plausible solution to this problem. To use the jquery upload plugin. Here is the [LINK](https://github.com/maxpavlov/jQuery-File-Upload.MVC3) for how to use the plugin with ASP.NET:

And here is the link for the demo of the plugin :

[DEMO](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/index.html)

I have not tried it myself because the requirements for my project had changed by the time I figured this out, but if anyone try this and it works do let me know!
Thanks!